# Not all custom claims add in GetProfileDataAsync appear in identity

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, claims

I am trying to add some custom claims through ProfileService GetProfileDataAsync. However, some of them come out others don't.

I have custom profile service that's derived from ProfileServic<ApplicationUser>. I override the GetProfileDataAsync as below:

```
public override async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    await base.GetProfileDataAsync(context);

    context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("given_name", "Joe"));
    context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("nickname", "jd"));
    context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("preferred_username", "Doe"));
    context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("sessionLife", "30"));
}
```

I expect to have four additional claims in my identity. But I just got one: given_name. In my client app configuration, I requested profile scope. I expect the nickname and preferred_username both come out since they are in the profile's resource group. The same as given_name does. nickname and preferred_username just don't come out. Is there some other filters that I need to overcome? Also, note that the last claim: sessionLife is not defined in the IdentityClaims table. Can I get it as well. Do I need to define a new identityClaim and identity resource for it?

---

For aaronR's request, here is the client side code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
{
    o.Authority = idpUrl;
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    o.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.ClientId = "mvc";
    o.ClientSecret = "secret";
    o.Scope.Add("email");                   
    o.Scope.Add("api1");
    o.Scope.Add("profile");                 //Your user profile information(first name, last name, etc.)
    o.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    o.ResponseType = "code id_token";
    o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    o.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

Comment: Please add the code from your client where you request the scopes and the other details.

Comment: Are you familiar with this article? https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/

Comment: I know some contents of this document. Definitely, there are more to try. Thanks.

Comment: I followed the link posted by Ruard, added two lines of calls to MapUniqueJsonKey for nickname and sessionLife. I got those claims to the client side user identity. However, I cannot do the same thing for the preferred_username field. I got InvalidCastException in the Microsoft code. I think I can leave without that field.